# Python XML + Java XML interoperability

Tags: java, python, xml, marshalling, interop

I need a recommendation for a pythonic library that can marshall python objects to XML(let it be a file).
I need to be able read that XML later on with Java (JAXB) and unmarshall it.
I know JAXB has some issues that makes it not play nice with .NET XML libraries so a recommendation on something that actually works would be great.

Comment: XML is XML. If a library can't parse valid XML properly then it's the library that's at fault, not any sense of "interoperability".

Comment: I don't care who is guilty in this situation. bottom line is that frameworks are incompatible. and I'm just want a recommendation on 2 frameworks that can play nice together. e.g see this
http://old.nabble.com/JAX-WS-%22namespace-of-schema-and-import-match%22-td21878972.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ignacio says, XML is XML.  On the python side, I recommend using `lxml`, unless you have more specific needs that are better met by another library.  If you are restricted to the standard library, look at `ElementTree` or `cElementTree`, which are also excellent, and which inspired (and are functionally mostly equivalent to) `lxml.etree`.

**Edit:** On closer look, it seems you are not just looking for XML, but for XML representations of objects.  For this, check out `lxml.objectify`, or Amara.  I haven't tried using them for interoperability with Java, but they're worth a try.  If you're just looking for a way to do data exchange, you might also try custom JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

The issue your are probably having is the default format of the Python and Java libraries you are using to marshal your objects. Any decent libraries including [**JAXB allows customisation**](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148715) of how objects should be represented in XML.

You need to decide what the structure of your XML should be then **use your libraries features to consume and emit your XML structure** rather than relying on the defaults which would never be the same across different libraries in different programming languages.